# Script70 Error in Frame-context

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, frames

i have a problem with the IE.

I have a local website (no webserver, fileprotocoll).

The website uses frames. Now i will use the JQuery tableSort Plugin.
So i collect the frame and then query all tables inside the Frame Context.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var frame = $('frame');
    frame.load(function () {
        var doc =  $(frame[3].contentWindow.document);
        $('table',doc).tablesorter({
            widgets: ["zebra", "filter"]
        });
    }); 
});
```

But this construct gives in IE8-11 a SCRIPT70: Erlaubnis verweigert / permission denied in Datei: jquery.min.js, Zeile: 4, Spalte: 5220

In Firefox is all fine.

Is there a solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in IE. In Chrome the error consits furthermore

The code that needs to be added in jQuery library in this case is:

See: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14535

```
try{
    document === document; //may cause permission denied
}
catch(err){
    document = window.document; //resets document, and no more permission denied errors.
}
```

Under the:

```
function Sizzle( selector, context, results, seed )
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, as a note, in later versions of jQuery this issue has been fixed by the Dev team. I upgraded from 2.0.3 to 2.2.4 and it resolved this issue as well